# Add item to "Add menu items" section in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am developing a wordpress theme. In the "Menus" there is a section:

[image]

How can I add an item to this programmatically? is it possible?

## Update:

If that is not possible, how can I add "icon" and "open in new tab" options.
I've searched a lot but didn't find anything. Can anybody introduce a source?

Comment: What would you like to add to this list? Is it a Custom Post Type?

Comment: I want to add icon and open in new tab option

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the **Link Target** and **CSS Classes** options from the **Screen Options** avaible in the top-right of the menu admin area. **Link Target** is a checkbox that provides the option to **Open link in a new tab**. **CSS Classes** is a text-field that you can use to add your custom CSS class. You can then display your icon using CSS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is only open in new tab option. I want icon and another options

Comment: If the CSS method to add icons is not feasible, an easy way to add icon-upload option would be use the [Menu Image plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-image/)

Comment: You could also use [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/) to add custom fields to menu items and display it in your theme or page-templates where required.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to create a theme, I can't use another plugins

Comment: You can take a look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/digamber89/e3c6289eaed0c6baf1d6d52f947bd3e7) and integrate it into your theme.

Comment: thank you, I found a solution: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/how-to-add-a-custom-field-in-the-advanced-menu-properties)